# Чтение localStorage в другом context script расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. 
Как можно читать localStorage данные из context_script_1.js в другом context_script_2.js

файл: context_script_1.js

```
window.localStorage.tabs_1_data = 'данные';
```

файл: context_script_2.js

```
alert( window.localStorage.tabs_1_data );
```

Comment: почему chrome.storage не используете?

Comment: цитата: почему chrome.storage не используете?   Можно поподробнее: как можно читать localStorage данные из context_script_1.js в другом context_script_2.js

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую прочитать нельзя, но можно передать примерно так:

**context_script_1.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    from:'script_1',
    data:window.localStorage
});
```

**context_script_2.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,callback){
    if(request.from == 'script_1'){
        alert(request.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Не работает, возможно требуется взаимодействие с background.js или / и заменить: runtime на extension = chrome.extension.sendMessage();

Comment: Походу данный метод, и событие предназначены для обмена: context_script.js с background.js,  а не: context_script_1.js с context_script_2.js