# Передать из background в content переменную

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Скажите, как передать переменную в background? В manifest'е нужные разрешения есть.

Пишу в background.js:

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }

if (localStorage["extension_id"])
  localStorage["extension_id"] = randomInteger(1, 1000000);
```

Как в итоге передать localStorage["extension_id"] в content.js для дальнейшего использования?

Comment: `var extension_id = localStorage["extension_id"];` в content.js не работает? Что значит передать в `background`?

Comment: undefined приходит, должно приходить число.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531749 посмотрите ответ тут, в вашем случае может помочь

Comment: если какое-то временное значение, то прочтите о [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Если значение значение должно хранится, то используйте [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Оно общее для content_scripts и background.

Comment: UserName, вы очень помогли!