# Доступ к localStorage для 2 скриптов Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть `app.js`, который подгружается в popup.html, и проводя там нужные манипуляции, пишет в **localStorage** нужные данные.

И есть скрипт `content.js`, который является сам по себе `content_script` и инжектится на страницу, открытую в браузере. 
Так вот, такой вопрос. Возможно ли каким-то образом дать доступ `content.js` к записам в `localStorage`, которые делаются из `app.js`?

Пробовал через Chrome API подтягивать его через executeScript, но, видимо, политика безопасности, либо моя необразованность не позволили этого сделать, в консоль выбивается

> ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined

Comment: Был уже [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531749/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-localstorage-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-context-script-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-chrome). Нельзя так просто взять и дать доступ, но можно перекинуть нужные данные по каналам связи между скриптами расширения

Comment: @Deliaz не дубликат. Там было два своих скрипта, тут один из скриптов - сторонний.

Comment: @PavelMayorov popup это не сторонний скрипт. Общение между двумя контент скриптами, бэкграунд скриптом и кодом, который выполняется в попапе работает по одной схеме в любых направлениях)